# Session Timeout in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, session

I have a problem,
in web.config i already state

```
<sessionState timeout="120" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

it is fine in my localhost.

but when i publish in Azure my session is gone before 120 minute.

Anyone can help?

Comment: How are you deploying the application? Is it deployed as WebApp or Cloud Service?

Comment: it deployed as webapp @GauravMantri

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the In-Proc session mode which would store session state in an individual web server's memory. Moreover, if the web server instance going down due to failures would result in the session data loss.

Since you could scale up your web app to multiple instances, using In-Proc session mode is not a good practice for your to host your web app on Azure, which could not share session state between multiple instances of your web app.

For a simple way, you could [Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604) or [Session state with Azure Redis cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/). Also, as mentioned in the [article](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/distributed-caching#sessionstate), the best solution if you have to use session state is to use a cache provider, such as [Session State Provider for Azure Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg185668.aspx).